# How to most effectivly split a string in two and put in two variables in perl?

Tags: regex, string, performance, perl

I read in a very large file in parts of 64KB, then do some changes to these parts, and then write it to an output file.

For that I always need to split the 64KB strings in two at the last occurrence of `\>`.

I surely could write a working script, using `rindex` and `substr` or with a regexp (maybe) or with `reverse`, but as this part of the code will be run about a million times, I just wonder what's the fastest way?

The code I use currently is:

```
#!C:/xampp/perl/bin/perl.exe -w

use strict;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = new CGI;

my $FileToRead.    = $q->param('FileToReadnameandpath');
my $FileToAppendTo = $q->param('addtofilenameandpath');
my $seekto         = $q->param('seekto');
my $lengthtoload   = $q->param('lengthtoload'); # 64000 currently
my $SizeFile       = -s $FileToRead ;
my $content;
my $pos            = 0;
my $leftover       = '';

open(READFILE,   "<",  $FileToRead);
open(APPENDFILE, ">>", $FileToAppendTo);
seek(READFILE, $seekto, 0);

for ( $pos = 0; $pos <= $SizeFile; $pos += $lengthtoload ) {
    read(READFILE, $content, $lengthtoload);
    $content = $leftover.$content;
    # $leftover = Text after last > in $content
    # $content = content without text after last >
    $content =~ s/ property="[^"]*"| prop2="[^"]*"| another="[^"]*"//g;
    print APPENDFILE $content;
}

$leftover =~ s/ property="[^"]*"| prop2="[^"]*"| another="[^"]*"//g;
print APPENDFILE $leftover;

close(READFILE);
close(APPENDFILE);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "reading and appending/writing should have been successful\n";
```

I just wrote my first test script in Perl yesterday, and actually I only need this one more instruction to finish what I need in Perl.

It needs to be as fast as possible. I know there can be a huge speed difference if I make some odd mistake, but I can't figure it out by myself in a reasonable amount of time.

Or should I use a totally other approach?

Comment: I will do a benchmark tomorrow. (Or just use rindex and substr, as that is probably the fastest as far as I have seen benchmarks on string-functions.)

Comment: Before making your code "as fast as possible", you should make it sure it is correct. For example, your code will remove things that look like attributes in character data which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Indeed given the data structure of the file I see a case where that regex would produce a false result. Maybe I really have to use an XML-parser.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're parsing HTML/XML with regexes.  [Don't do that](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-match-XML-HTML-or-other-nasty-ugly-things-with-a-regex).  Use an existing XML parser.

If memory is a concern, [use a SAX parser](https://metacpan.org/search?q=sax&size=20) which will read the document as a stream.  If performance is a concern, several of those modules are wrappers around parsers written in C and so will be very fast.

Also your code has no security features and will allow someone to append to any file they like.

Comment: I'll keep the SAX-parser in mind. In the specific use case (preprocessing a 40+GByte file so to reduce it to like 60%) it woudn't be suitable in regard to speed. But in general I do use an XML-parser for XML-data. - I just thought again about it, and maybe I have to take the slower speed of the XML-parser, because I can't be sure about the property-values. (I can be sure about the generel structure of the data.)

Comment: @John How do you know it's not fast enough?